# Seleção não apresenta dados na tela (php e mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, crud

```
<?php


class categoria {
    public function selecao($pesquisa){
        require_once 'conexao.php';
        $con = new conexao();
        $conn = $con->conectar();
        $sql = "select * from categoria where nome LIKE '%$pesquisa%'";
        $resultado= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        var_dump($resultado);
        $i=0;
//Creio que o erro está no código abaixo.
        while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo "$line[$i]";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    public function insercao(){

    }
    public function remover(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Não precisa colocar a variável entre aspas. Tente `echo $line[$i];`.

Comment: a solução foi simples: while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo $line[0];
            echo $line[1];
            echo $line[2];